# Changing Python version on OSX

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python 2.7 installed on mac and I would like to use the CRYPTO module, but it doesn't support so installed home-brew and then downloaded python 2.7.9. I changed the path on ~/.bash_profile to /usr/local/bin

Yet, when I try which python it uses the default one.

$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Comment: Did you close your shell after updating your `.bash_profile`, or otherwise reload the file?

Comment: I forgot to close the shell, its working now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use virtualenv to create a virtual enviroment for your project, which provides you isolated Python environment specific to one Python interpreter.

[Official Python package installation guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments).

Quick example:

```
 virtualenv -p /path/to/my/python venv
 source venv/bin/activate
 pip install pycrypto
```

If you need to activate virtualenv in your `.bash_profile` add line (. instead of source):

```
 . /Users/you/venv/bin/activate
```